# How to read from the internal clipboard of a Telerik Kendo Diagram?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, clipboard, diagram

I have a system that allows users to create multiple diagrams. I want to be able to copy a part of one diagram, close it, run another and paste in what I have copied. The problem is that the diagram.copy() and diagram.paste() functions use an internal clipboard which is lost when I close the original diagram, so there's nothing to paste when I open the other one.

I'm very new to Telerik, so I don't really know how to approach this. I tried digging through the documentation, but I couldn't see any way to interact with the internal clipboard other than the two functions.

Preferably I'd like to be able to read the internal clipboard, copy it to a global variable and then read the variable back when opening the destination diagram.
Or maybe there's a way to read the selected shapes into a variable without using the copy() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the source code, I've found it's stored in the variable diagram._clipboard . You can run this sample and inspect: https://dojo.telerik.com/onunEkib

However, as an undocumented feature, this can change and break when upgrading your Kendo version. Plus, as this is the diagram's internal data, it can be invalid for the target diagram.

What I'd do is a custom copy button that gets the current selection through the [select method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/diagram/methods/select).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've ended up just using select() as well. I then take advantage of the fact that I'm working on an MVC application and just send the data to the server and store it in the Session variable.